# FolderBrowserDialog - Win32Exception occurred - The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to use the FolderBrowserDialog from WPF like this:

```
public static bool BrowseFolder(out string folderName)
{
   using (System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog())
   {
        var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        folderName = dlg.SelectedPath;
        return result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
   }
}
```

When using "break on exception" in Visual Studio 2010 I get an Exception after closing the Dialog in the ShowDialog() call. I'm curious why this occurs.

Exception: Win32Exception
Message: The parameter is incorrect
Stacktrace:  at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.SetFocus(HandleRef hWnd)

**Update**
I also tried to set the parent explicitly, but the exception was thrown nonetheless.

```
var w = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(parent);
System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window i = new WindowWrapper(w.Handle);
result = dlg.ShowDialog(i);
```

Comment: Is there any more to this?  Do you use any other Forms in your app?  Testing this on a blank WPF app doesn't raise any exceptions and runs fine.

Comment: I created an empty test application with only that function and a call to that function and the exception occurs. You must activate "Break on exception" in Visual Studio 2010 to see the application (Debug->Exceptions...->Checkboxes)

Comment: You need to show the value of the exception's StackTrace property.

Comment: The value of the Stacktrace property is posted already. It contains only one line.

Comment: I get the exact same exception every time I show WinForms message boxes or dialogs from my WPF app.

Answer (score 9):

This is just a bit of interop nastiness.  The WPF code tries to set the focus back to the main window when the dialog is closing.  Problem is, the dialog has disabled the window so it can't receive the focus yet.  WPF is too eager to change the focus and doesn't otherwise know anything about the dialog behavior.  Nothing actually goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing it without using the "using" statement, perhaps it is getting cleaned up too quickly.

Answer (score -1):

I do belive you need a windows forms host to run anything from the Windows.Forms namespace... try it out!

Comment: the windows forms host control / component is in the Toolbox btw

Comment: Putting a Windows Forms host on a WPF window didn't help.