# When I write in a TextBox I have a error 'The window identifier is invalid ' in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, textbox

I am doing a Simple "Crud" without database, and when i write anything in any of my textBox of my project i have an exception getting thrown.

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Window handle is invalid',

This only happens when I write in the textbox, I didn't find any similar question here on Stack Overflow. If someone can help me I'll be very grateful. The complete error is this one:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Window identifier is invalid
  Source=WindowsBase
  StackTrace:
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMessageW(MSG& msg, HandleRef hWnd, Int32 uMsgFilterMin, Int32 uMsgFilterMax)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.GetMessage(MSG& msg, IntPtr hwnd, Int32 minMessage, Int32 maxMessage)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.WpfVisualTreeService.VisualTree.RootSourceFinder.HwndWatcher()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Note: this error I've been having since yesterday, but when I turned on the computer today it wasn't happening. It started after a few runs, the same way it started yesterday, but now even if I restart the pc, it's running

CreateWindow.xalm:

```
<Window x:Class="Atividade_1_Luz.CreateView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Atividade_1_Luz"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="CreateView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid >
        <StackPanel Background="AliceBlue" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="295,60,307,62">
            <TextBlock FontSize="15" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Register Product" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="28" Width="138"/>
            <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,5,10,0" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Name" FontSize="10"/>
            <TextBox Margin="25,-10,28,5" Height="24" Width="100" Text="{Binding Name}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     />
            <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,5,10,0" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Category" FontSize="10"/>
            <TextBox Margin="25,-10,28,5" Height="24" Width="100" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Category}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     />
            <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,5,10,0" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Description" FontSize="10"/>
            <TextBox Margin="25,-10,28,5" Height="24" Width="100" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     />

            <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,5,10,0" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Price" FontSize="10"/>
            <TextBox Margin="25,-10,28,5" Height="24" Width="100" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Price}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="45">
                <Button Command="{Binding Command}" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Back" Margin="30,0,10,0"/>
                <Button Command="{Binding CommandCreate}" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Create" Margin="20,0,10,0"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
        <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299" Margin="295,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

UpdateWindow.xalm:

```
<Window x:Class="Atividade_1_Luz.UpdateView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Atividade_1_Luz"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="UpdateView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        
        <StackPanel Background="AliceBlue" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="295,60,307,62">
            <TextBlock FontSize="15" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Update Product" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="28" Width="138"/>
            <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,5,10,0" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Name" FontSize="10"/>
            <TextBox Margin="25,-10,28,5" Height="24" Width="100" Text="{Binding Name}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     />
            <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,5,10,0" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Category" FontSize="10"/>
            <TextBox Margin="25,-10,28,5" Height="24" Width="100" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Category}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     />
            <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,5,10,0" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Description" FontSize="10"/>
            <TextBox Margin="25,-10,28,5" Height="24" Width="100" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     />

            <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,5,10,0" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Price" FontSize="10"/>
            <TextBox Margin="25,-10,28,5" Height="24" Width="100" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Price}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="45">
                <Button Command="{Binding Command}" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Back" Margin="30,0,10,0"/>
                <Button Command="{Binding CommandCreate}" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Create" Margin="20,0,10,0"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
        <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299" Margin="295,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I don't know if this is normal, but there's no problem with this line not being used?
[image: Image Local:]

Comment: What is happening in your ViewModel when you edit the text? If you remove the binding and try to type in the text box, does it still throw the error?

Comment: hi thanks for answering, so i just tested without the bindings and the same error happened, and in my modelView i do nothing while the input is inserted, only when the create button for example is pressed, but the program throws the error as soon as I type a letter or 2, I'll put my modelView in the post.

Comment: actually I'm not able to edit my post, I don't know why :(

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer here at this link: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923081/16804862)

this solution really helped me basically in your visual studio you should go to Tools > Options > Debugging > General > and disable UI Interface Debugging Tools for XAML option.

Hope to help someone with the same problem.